# Vanishing point existence

Tags: geometry, 3d, transformation, projective-geometry, projection

Suppose I have considered example of
perspective projection.I have one railway track with two lines meets at point say,$X$ at infinity which is theoretical approach.And this X is called vanishing point.But practically  this $X$ doesn't exists.

My first question is how we can say it doesn't exist, but when we see real image of railway track they intersects at $X?$

My second question is if it exists then during projection how this $X$ is projects in projection plane?  Is it projecting like normal point projection $(x, y,z)$ to in view plane $(x_p, y_p, z_p)?$

N. B- I don't want that answer which is in details manner. I want just intuition which is brief and easy to understand.

Comment: In projective geometry it *does* exist. Check out this question and answers .. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795673/1257

Comment: @brainjam no this not my questions answerer. I have asked perspective projection.

Comment: Isn't this image clear enough? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point#/media/File:Vanishing_point.svg

Comment: @pauca you mean in 3D space they don't intersects, but in projection plane they intersects?

Comment: False premise. In a **real** image of railway tracks the rails do not meet at the vanishing point, because no **real** railroad track goes perfectly straight without end.

Comment: @Niyon Yes, that's quite clear from that image. They intersect at the point where a line from the point of view, parallel to the tracks, intersects the projection plane.

Comment: @Pauca  could you insert your comments in answer, I will accept it.

Comment: As already said by others, mathematicians have developed extended versions of the 3D euclidean space where the crossing point of parallel lines really exist. Me and others who know nothing (except the existence, maybe) of such geometry still can say "parallel lines meet in the vanishing point in the infinity". But that's lousy speak (=nonsense) because the 3D space that we think doesn't have such point. I have shaped up. I have ceased to talk about vanishing point in infinity. I'll say that the perspective images of parallel lines meet in their vanishing point on the 2D imaging plane.

Answer (score -1):

X doesn't exist in reality, since the railroad tracks are parallel,
but it exists in the projection plane.

In the following link, you have the explanation :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point

### Projections of two sets of parallel lines lying in some plane πA appear to converge, i.e. the vanishing point associated with that pair, on a horizon line, or vanishing line H formed by the intersection of the image plane with the plane parallel to πA and passing through the pinhole.

Mateo.

Comment: It's not my question answer. Please elaborate more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).